# Why to use the product rule in the differentiation of $z=re^{i\theta}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis) Wikipedia article on Winding Numbers, under the sub-section "Complex Analysis," is described the following:

> In complex analysis, the winding number of a closed curve C in the complex plane can be expressed in terms of the complex coordinate $z=x+iy$. Specifically, if we write $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $$dz=e^{i\theta}dr+ire^{i\theta}d\theta $$ and therefore $$\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{dr}{r}+id\theta=d[\ln r]+id\theta,$$

and the sub-section goes on a little before ending. My question is - why have they used the product rule in the differentiation of $z=re^{i\theta}$, when $r$ is not specified as a function of $\theta$, for this is how the first equation must have been reached ?

Comment: You are computing differentials $df(x,y)=f_x(x,y)dx+f_y(x,y)dy$. Then $dz=d(re^{i\theta})=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(re^{i\theta})dr+\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(re^{i\theta}d\theta)=e^{i\theta}dr+ire^{i\theta}d\theta$.

Comment: You can write $z$ in two forms: Cartesian form ($x + iy$) and polar form ($re^{i\theta}$). In both instances, the complex number $z$ depends on two real parameters (either $x$ and $y$, or $r$ and $\theta$). The fact that there is a relationship between them isn't relevant here.

Comment: $r$ and $\theta$ are two separate variables, just like $x$ and $y$ are two separate variables.

Comment: Exactly - if they are two independent variables, then differentiating one will not effect the other ?

Comment: If you differentiate with respect to one, you treat the other constant, that's true, that is exactly what partial differentitation is.

Comment: We have $C=\{f(t) : t\in \Bbb R\}$ where $f$ is continuous and periodic with period $2\pi,$ and $f(t)$ is 1-to-1 on $t\in [0,2\pi).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $z = re^{i\theta}$, $z$ is a function of the variables $r$ and $\theta$, so the rule being used could be described as a multivariable chain rule (for differential $1$-forms), rather than a product rule:

$$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}dr + \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}d\theta = e^{i\theta}dr + ire^{i\theta}d\theta.$$

This is just a multivariable extension of the rule $dy = \dfrac{dy}{dx}dx$ that is often seen when learning about integration by substitution.

Comment: That really has nothing to do with it. Are you familiar with the rule $dy = \dfrac{dy}{dx}dx$ where $y$ is a function of $x$?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with this. It's a bit like "canceling" the $dx's$ so I was taught...

Comment: You can think of it like that, but that isn't what's happening. Do you know partial differentiation?

Comment: But I understand that when we differentiate, $z=re^{i\theta}$ with respect to $\theta$ the $r$ is constant unless it is related somehow to $\theta$, so that's why I couldn't understand why they used the product (chain...) rule.

Comment: They didn't. They used partial differentiation. When you differentiate $z = re^{i\theta}$ with respect to $r$, you treat $\theta$ as constant so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = e^{i\theta}$. When you differentiate $z$ with respect to $\theta$, you treat $r$ as constant so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} = ire^{i\theta}$. Can you see why these two things are true?

Comment: So could you please try to explain what it is you are still unsure of? I'm happy to move this discussion to chat if you want to.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I doubt whether OP really understands differential forms.

Comment: @FrankScience: I never assumed they did, my only reference to them was paranthetical.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese But stuff like $dz$, $dr$, $d\theta$ are really 1-forms, and most textbooks as far as I saw just define the winding number (for a smooth curve) as $1/(2i\pi)\oint_C dz/z$.

Comment: I am well aware of that, but I didn't introduce $1$-forms into the discussion, the OP did. I am trying to answer their question without having to teach them differential forms.

Comment: @pbs You can indeed see what they did as applying the product rule (which is a property of $d$ too as well as for the derivative). If you have two functions $f$ and $g$, then $d(fg)=fdg+gdf$. Then $d(re^{i\theta})=e^{i\theta}dr+rd(e^{i\theta})$. Now, you said you know that $df(x)=f'(x)dx$ for functions of one variable. Use it in the last summand.